# iPhoto like slideshow in c#

Tags: c#, slideshow, iphoto

How would I go about creating cool slide show that iPhoto in Mac creates?
For example, if you look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9R2lGdv4u-k
it explains how it has built in themes. It is not just moving pictures arond, it also has flipping effect, show pictures in black and white and many others

Is there any library that I can use?
I guess there won't be anything built into .net framework but I would think there must be some 3rd party library that make this possible.

Comment: You can place images on your page using CSS or CSS3 effects to place in different direction and then you can use jquery lightbox to make a slider effect : http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: the goal is to produce a video file

Comment: You can use the lightbox to display video's as well, http://bit.ly/Lck9P7